# Can't log into Magento Admin, "Invalid Captcha" error appears

Tags: magento2

I cannot login to Magento admin, I just get this response every time, when I initially entered my login details, there was no captcha there, it appears after I try to login.

[image]

then once I've tried to login using the captcha:

[image]

any help please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please make captcha 1 -> 0 in `core_config_data` table.

Try after cleaning cache and if not work then reindex.

Update below row in database:

```
Update core_config_data  set value=0 WHERE  path LIKE  '%admin/captcha/enable%'
```

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

If you don't find this row then insert it.

Comment: I have tried to do this, there is no captcha row in the core_config_data table, so I wasn't able to edit it.

Comment: Captcha is not excatly value i think,  please search like wise

Comment: I can't find anything in core_config_data that is anything related to my issue.

Any other ideas? Or am I missing the wrong row in database? btw, I'm on Magento 2.2.5

Comment: I have upated my answer please try it

Answer (score 12):

**Run commands in the magento root instead of changing in database:**

Disable admin login captcha:

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/captcha/enable 0
```

Unlock the admin user ( e.g admin )

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin
```

Reindex and Clean the cache

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: also you may clear the cookies in your browser to avoide to try to get the same token

Comment: This solution also worked for me on the admin's "Forgot Password" screen

Answer (score 0):

```
Update core_config_data set value=0 WHERE path LIKE '%admin/captcha/enable%'
```

Comment: answer is missing closing single quote

Answer (score 0):

Not compatible with Magento 2.3.4
Path 'admin/captcha/enable' is missing

Answer (score 0):

Look for the captcha_log table in the database, search for the username in the value column and erase any rows containing it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to the other answers, you can also, do this from inside `app/etc/env.php`
You can disable by adding this to the `env.php` configuration.

Add this:

```
'modules'  => [
      'MSP_ReCaptcha' => '0',
      'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => '0'
]
```

Example (I normally add at the end, and you can add additional modules as well):

```
    ],
    'queue' => [
         'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1
    ],
    'modules'  => [
         'MSP_ReCaptcha' => '0',
         'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => '0'
    ]
];
```

After, you will need to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

OK: php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin
Wrong: php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin --admin-password=******
direct password set is not more permitted.