# Can't login to Magento 2 Admin.... Constantly asking for CAPTCHA

Tags: magento2, login, captcha, recaptcha

Having issues attempting to login to the back end of my M2 store. My login is correct, but when I attempt to login, I get an incorrect CAPTCHA message (even though there was no CAPTCHA on the initial login screen) and then I try again and this time it tells me I'm locked out.

I saw a post similar to this here ([Can't log into Magento Admin, "Invalid Captcha" error appears](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240454/cant-log-into-magento-admin-invalid-captcha-error-appears)) but this seems to just disable CAPTCHA completely and to me, that's more like a band-aid than a real solution. I certainly don't want to disable the CAPTCHA. I just want to resolve this issue and login successfully instead.

Comment: There is another way: create a new admin user by using command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can update password of your admin login by below command:

**`php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=abcd --admin-email=abcd@gmail.com --admin-firstname=ABCD --admin-lastname=EFGH`**

**Point to be noted:**
After run above command, it will ask to add password. Please update your password and start using you backend using the password.

You can keep everything same as your last admin user detail like admin user, email, firstname and lastname but **just update your password**

Ignore adding this `--admin-password` in above command for security purpose.

You can keep the same old password and enter that once again.

After done with above you can login with your current details.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to unlock an administrator account.

Use this command to unlock the account of an administrator that was locked, typically because of multiple incorrect login attempts:

```
bin/magento admin:user:unlock {username}
```

You must specify the administrator’s username. Example:

```
$ bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin
The user account "admin" has been unlocked
```

Source : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, try to unlock the admin user through this command

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock {admin_user}
```

If that doesn't work, try to reset the password for that admin user and try to login

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user={admin_user} --admin-password=admin@123
```

Lastly, if the above things not work, then create the new admin user

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=new_admin --admin-password=admin@123 --admin-email=admin@gmail.com --admin-firstname=NewAdmin --admin-lastname=NewAdmin
```

**New Admin Credentials will be
username:- new_admin
password:- admin@123**

Comment: We should not add "--admin-password" for security reasons